# Xcode Source Control git locations

Tags: xcode, git

This won't be a technical question, just a general knowledge one.
I'm just starting to use Source Control with Xcode 11 and was wondering *where* the git repositories were actually stored ? It matters to me for safekeeping purposes.
Up until now, I have regularly duplicated my Project Folder before working on changes, keeping my files on my desktop, which is constantly backed up to iCloud.

Are git repos backed up to iCloud in Xcode ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A git repo is just a folder. For an Xcode project, that folder is inside the the project folder. So wherever and however you back up the project, that is how you back up the repo: whether by Time Machine, iCloud, explicit copying, or whatever.

There is *also* the very nice ability for a git repo to back *itself* up by keeping a copy in the cloud, such as at GitHub. But that would be up to you; you can use git perfectly well without doing that.

To put it another way, I like to look at git as doing *three* things:

- The world's greatest Undo mechanism.
- A backup mechanism.
- A means of allowing multiple programmers to collaborate coherently.

Your situation sounds like you're interested only in the first of those aspects of git, and that's just fine. You can back up the repo when you back up your other project files, and you presumably have no one to collaborate with.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Matt. I'm actually interested in the 2 first points, the backup is paramount. But I see absolutely NO extra folder in my Project folder since I added Source Control. I did set up my GitHub account with Xcode in order to push my project to it regularly, for backup purposes, but I don't do this as often as I use the "commit" action.

Comment: @Esowes The git folder is named .git. Files and folders that start with a dot are hidden in the Finder. If you press Cmd-Shift-dot in the Finder, you will see the hidden files and folders and be able to see .git folder inside your project folder.

Comment: Yeah, what he said. All of what he said. :)